# Differential multi-feedback band-pass filter design

Tags: differential-amplifier

I am trying to design a multi-feedback differential band-pass filter.

While doing calculations I just took Texas Instr. design guides, but nowhere is mentioned exactly how to realize the filter for the required specifications.

Example: I need a pass band ripple of <0.5 dB and pass band 300 Hz to 6 kHz. Attenuation roll-off rate required is 40 dB/decade on either side.

I did a simulation and tried to tune with trial-and-error values. I am getting peak overshoots near cut-off points.

How to realise the filter with a flat pass band?

Please share reference design calculations if available.

[image]

[[image: ko][2]]

Answer (score 0):

Use a 2nd-order Butterworth Sallen-Key highpass filter in series with a 2nd-order Butterworth Sallen-Key lowpass filter.

Comment: Yes - I agree with Audioguru because for such a large bandwidth it would be not a good idea to use the lowpass-bandpass transformation for designing a 4th-order bandpass (two 2nd-order bandpass stages in series).